# unable to parse sample json. Getting JsonParseException

Tags: jackson

Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character (' ' (code 160)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
at [Source: (String)"{
    "CorrelationId": "{{$guid}}",
    "UserId": 50,
    "SenderId": "ICICIL",
    "MSISDN": "9845628794",
    "Message": "test message",
    "MTag": "12345",
    "MsgType": 1,
"Costcenter" : "B99-50330"
}"; line: 2, column: 2]

Comment: Please add what is the exact `json` you are trying to parse.

Comment: You probably need to escape some of those quotes `\\"` or `\"`. You should supply more of the code doing the processing as well as the error you're getting

Comment: {
    "CorrelationId": "{{$guid}}",
    "UserId": 50,
    "SenderId": "ICICIL",
    "MSISDN": "9845628794",
    "Message": "test message",
    "MTag": "12345",
    "MsgType": 1,
    "Costcenter" : "B99-50330"
}